# How to use tomcat with spring without web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS application deployed on Tomcat 7. I am deploying the application on Tomcat without any `web.xml` file.

I want to use spring for injecting some of the dependencies in my project. I am not using any `XML` file to configure beans, instead I have created a class and annotated it with `@Configuration` annotation, which contains all the bean definitions. Now, I am trying to use that bean by annotating a field in a separate class with `@Autowired`, but the field is `null`.

How should I make spring work with this setup ?

EDIT:
I was able to initialize spring application context , by creating a `web.xml` in WEB-INF/ with the following contents.

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

I checked the tomcat logs , and verified that the bean is created by spring. But the problem is when I try to use that bean, the field in the class is null.

Comment: Just tag every useful question as "too Broad". Great work moderators!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), which helps you develop a web application as easy as developing a stand-alone application that you can "just run".

According to official website of Spring Boot, you can create

- Create stand-alone Spring applications
- Embed Tomcat, Jetty or Undertow directly (no need to deploy WAR files)
- Provide opinionated 'starter' POMs to simplify your Maven configuration
- Automatically configure Spring whenever possible
- Provide production-ready features such as metrics, health checks and externalized configuration
- Absolutely no code generation and no requirement for XML configuration

You can learn it in just 1 hour I found this YouTube video very interesting watch [Getting Started with Spring Boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbPSjI4tt10&t=6s).

Comment: This maybe suitable for a new project, but I can't switch this existing project to spring-boot.

Answer (score 0):

web.xml is used as a starting point while tomcat container starts.
If you want to bypass this, you can write a simple Java program and inside main() function just call Spring to load application context and provide the path of your apps applicationContext.

More details : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

Comment: But the problem is there is no main function in the application

Comment: You can chose any starting point. However your main application comes up, you can load spring context there and all the spring features would be enabled

Comment: I don't understand "You can choose any starting point" . What do you mean by that ?

Comment: The way we have a main() function as an entry point for any Java application. Whats entry point of your application ? What you deploy in tomcat ?

Comment: I deploy a JAX-RS application. There may be an entry point, but I haven't defined it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use @Autowired the in a Class it first has to be a Bean. You can do this by annotating the Class with @Component or by using the @Bean Annotation in the Configuration.

```
@Bean
Yourclass yourclass(){
     return new YourClass();
}
```

Second you will have to add the @ComponentScan Annotation to your Configuration.

```
@ComponentScan("your.package")
@Configuration
```

Third you must instantiate an ApplicationContext. For example like this

```
JavaConfigApplicationContext context = new JavaConfigApplicationContext(YourConfig.class);
```

Because it is a Webapplication it probably would be best to have a look at [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html), implement your own and initialize the Context there.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the way to initialize the Spring Dispatcher Servlet. 
You need to implement the interface `WebApplicationInitializer` and in this class, you pass all the Java configurations needed for your application.

You have to define `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` where you can register your configuration class :

```
context.register(MyConfig.class);
```

or you can define the base packages containing all your config classes :

```
context.setConfigLocation("com.example.app.config");
```

Full example :

```
    public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context
          = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.example.app.config");

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container
          .addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Last thing, if you use maven, don't forget to set the property `failOnmissingwebxml` to `false` in the `pom.xml`.

You can find more info [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-vs-java-config)

Comment: After going through the docs and other similar questions, I created a web.xml and added a listener `<web-app>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>`  Now, this listener is loaded and spring bean is initialized, but when I try to use the bean, it is null. I have tried both @Autowired and @Resource annoations.

Comment: I updated my question, and look at the link that I posted